# Bundle Overloading Docs

Tags: android, overloading, bundle

I'm attempting to use a Bundle in my Android application (Kotlin) and I don't understand the documentation for the API.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

For example:

```
public void putFloat(String key, float value)
```

Okay, seems simple, but why is the function just not overloaded as:

```
public void put(String key, float value)
```

Also, why is there no:

```
public void putInt(String key, Int value)
```

or

```
public void put(String key, Int value)
```

I know the programmers that put together the API must be pretty smart and spend some time thinking about their API, so I must not be understanding something. What am I not understanding?

Thanks.

Edit:

Let me clarify why I'm asking this question with some rambling since I didn't appreciate a response I got below:

If the API doesn't overload, then how can certain programming tasks be completed. For example, if I use a generic type, how will the programmer know which function to call? What will get do if the key was not put before calling the get method? Wouldn't get methods overloaded with a default value type have solved this issue? What happens if the put type doesn't match the get type for a given key?

The API seems to go to lengths to avoid overloading (IMHO, a basic Object Oriented feature), and overloading would have solved so many of the issues I see. Is it more likely the API is poorly written or that I don't understand something fundamental? I'm going with I don't understand something fundamental or at least there's a high probability I don't understand something.

Since my confusion in this API seems to lead me to the lack of overloading, I focused my question there. If the consensus was something like, "It's not overloaded because it isn't overloaded.", then I know there was nothing fundamental I'm missing, hoping to avoid the [Dunning-Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) Effect by not assuming the author didn't know what they were doing.

Android is using Bundle for the experimental Saved State module and they are using it internally. I'm attempting to understand the Bundle API so I can use the Saved State module effectively. Reading the Bundle API docs confused me so much that I figured there was something I'm not understanding on how to read the docs. As noted below, I was missing one aspect of the docs. I was thinking the docs were obsolete and Google forgot to update them and I should be ignoring them.

Maybe I don't understand intended use of the Bundle API by application programmers? Maybe the Bundle API was only intended for internal use and there is some set of inherited classes I'm not seeing? Maybe...??? I can't speculate on what I don't know I don't know.

Someone may answer, "Never use the Bundle API directly. It was written as a 'C' interface for low level use and they exposed it back in API version 1.0 and since forgot to mark it obsolete. You should be using class SomeBundleDerived class instead. The docs are old, ignore them." BTW, that answer would make my day.

Or maybe the API was just poorly designed? I hate thinking an API this crude is being considered as the basis of default values in the Saved State module, but if that is what is going on... I'd rather know now.

I don't like how people treat others on Stackoverflow who would just like to get some help. The tactic of framing a question differently than intended and then shooting it down instead of just answering the question asked has the effect of being unwelcoming to learning. I'm tired of the abuse given out by people claiming they want to help others but are really all about handing out platitudes and claiming superiority. Get a life, preferably one that doesn't involve helping others understand technical material.

You can put a reply below if you like, I won't be reading it. The abuse is not worth an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> why is the function just not overloaded as: `public void put(String key, float value)`

Probably for parallelism with the getter names. In Java, you cannot have two methods with the same name and same parameter list, differing only in the return type. So, we need `getFloat()` to distinguish from `getInt()`, `getBoolean()`, etc. On `Bundle`, they chose to name the setters following the same convention. On `Intent` for the extras, they didn't.

However, in general, questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are not great for Stack Overflow, as frequently only Developer X can answer. Everyone else can just offer guesses.

> Also, why is there no `public void putInt(String key, Int value)`

That is inherited from `BaseBundle`.

Comment: I didn't ask "why did Developer X make Decision Y?". While I appreciate the speculation, it does not answer my question. My question is about understanding the API. Not overloading makes usage impossible in situations where the type is not known. "What am I not understanding?" Thank you for the BaseBundle, I didn't know the online docs didn't expose public members. Seems like a documentation error since a public base method is public in the derived class and forcing the reader to look though every base class in the hierarchy to find what is public is not tenable.

Comment: @Mitch: "I didn't ask "why did Developer X make Decision Y?"." -- your question "why is the function just not overloaded as?" is shorthand for "why did the Google engineers who created this function make the decision to name it what they did?". We cannot answer that definitively -- only the Google engineers who made the decision can. So, yes, you asked "why did Developer X make Decision Y?".

Comment: @Mitch: "I didn't know the online docs didn't expose public members" -- they do, but the inherited sections are collapsed by default. For example, in [the `Bundle` docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html), you will find "Inherited Constants" and "Inherited Methods" sections, with entries that you can fold open to get at the stuff that `Bundle` inherits. It's a different way of rendering the JavaDocs than lots of sites use, with pros and cons. Not noticing inherited stuff is definitely one of the cons.

Comment: Okay, I see that section now. I don't like it, but far better to know I have to click it and I have to hunt all the way up the inheritance chain to get the docs. ... not your fault, but I really don't like it. Thanks.